# iPhone - CMMotionManager properties and iPhone hardware

Tags: iphone, hardware, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

Do someone know, for each property of CMMotionmanager.deviceMotion and their subproperties, on what kind of hardware they are based on (magnetometer, accelerometer, gyroscope, ...) ?

My question is about **HARDWARE**, not software.

I need to know from which piece of hardware the CMMotionManager get its values to know on which kind of iPhone my CMMotionManager calls will work. And to write consequent text on my web site.

So what piece of hardware is use to build :

deviceMotion.attitude.roll
deviceMotion.attitude.pitch
deviceMotion.attitude.yaw
deviceMotion.rotationRate (sole gyroscope ? Iphone 4 / 4S with iOS4)
deviceMotion.gravity (sole accelerometer ? So it should work on all iPhones with iOS4)
deviceMotion.userAcceleration (sole accelerometer ? So it should work on all iPhones with iOS4)
deviceMotion.magneticFied (sole magnetometer ? Iphone 3GS / 4 / 4S with iOS4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** (hardware):

The deviceMotion property is only available on devices having both an accelerometer and a gyroscope. This is because its sub-properties are the result of a sensor  fusion algorithm i.e. both signals are evaluated together in order to decrease the estimation errors. Especially gravity estimation on fast moved devices is still hard work when high precision is demanded (car navigation, satellite positioning,... face the same problems). Popular fusion algorithms are for instance the [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) and derivatives but I guess the CMMotionManager's internal implementation is based on simpler and thus faster algorithms.

Given that, you have only the raw sensor data properties of CMMotionManger `accelerometerData` and `gyroData` that are related 1:1 to a sensor - and in case of iOS 5 `magnetometerData`. `deviceMotion` and all its sup-properties are the calculated result of the internal implementation of fusion algorithms.

**Old answer:**

**iOS 4.x:**

CMMotionManager supports gyroscope and accelerometer. It provides for isXxxAvailable and isXxxActive to query hardware capabilities and determine the status, e.g. [accelerometerAvailable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/accelerometerAvailable) and [accelerometerActive](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/accelerometerActive). Furtheron there is a simple but quite efficient sensor fusion algorithm called DeviceMotion if the device has an accelerometer and a gyroscope on board - compass is not needed and thus not used. Analog to the sensors you use [deviceMotionAvailable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/deviceMotionAvailable) and [deviceMotionActive](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/deviceMotionActive) for getting information.

Magnetometer is only available via CLLocationManager.

I experienced sometimes trouble with deviceMotionActive when the app is getting to foreground again after suspending (got `true` although DeviceMotion was definitely stopped before).

**iOS 5.x:**
Magnetometer support is added to CMMotionManager and handled like the two other sensors.

**General:**
You can use CMMotionManager even on iPhone 3g (with iOS4). You don't have access to CMDeviceMotion but can query accelerometer updates. Thus you have to use low pass filtering to get a gravity estimation and it's far more worse than DeviceMotion.

You should not use the pre-iOS 4 interface UIAccelerometerDelegate.

Comment: Well, I thought my question was clear enough. I ask for hardware, not software. My online website is not on iOS. When you read it, you way even not have an iPhone.

Comment: Oops, sorry. When I started answering, your question was not yet updated

Comment: No problem. Anyway, do you have a solution for the hardware part of the subject ?

Comment: Are you sure that deviceMotion.rotationRate or deviceMotion.magneticFied won't be available on a 3GS because of the lack of gyroscope ?

Comment: Yes, see first paragraph of Event Handling Guide / Core Motion: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW26

Answer (score 0):

See the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> A CMMotionManager object is the gateway to the motion services
>   provided by iOS. These services provide an application with
>   accelerometer data, rotation-rate data, magnetometer data, and other
>   device-motion data such as attitude. These types of data originate
>   with a device’s accelerometers and (on some models) its magnetometer
>   and gyroscope.

Comment: Ah ah, easy. I've read it. Do you mean that CMMotionManager require the three hardware pieces so it will only work on an iPhone 4x ?

Comment: No, it uses the accelerometers. And the magnetometer and gyroscope only on certain devices that suport it. It just will work better on those devices I guess.

Comment: It seems that 4.0 and higher have access to accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer. Device motion begins with 5.0

Comment: Just look at "avaibility" at each function

Comment: @simpleBob : Well, I thought my question was clear enough. I ask for hardware, not software. My online website is not on iOS. When you read it, you way even not have an iPhone. I use the CMMotionManager, but I don't see anywhere with wich piece of hardware it build its return values.